# Auto Select Option Tag by default in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, drop-down-menu, html-select

Does anybody have an idea on how to auto select option tag?

I checked at the spring form tag library but cant see any property related to an option value being selected by default when the JSP is rendered.

I basically have this:

```
<p>
    <label for="plantLabel" class="label">Plant:</label> 
    <form:select path="strPlant" >
        <form:option value="-" label="--Select Please--" />
        <form:options items="${plants}" itemLabel="strPlant"
            itemValue="strPlant" />
    </form:select>
</p>
```

and, I want an option from the list (ie. items="${plants}" , say 'NeemTree') to be shown as already selected when the page loades.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "selected Option" will be calculate by Spring MVC based on the `path=""` attribute.

In above case I think,

Either the value of `path="strPlant"` is null

OR

the array/collection/map represented by `items="${plants}"` attribute does not contain an element corresponding to `path="strPlant"` value.

e.g.
if `path="strPlant"` results in String `NeemTree`, `items=""` must have `NeemTree` as element.

`itemLabel="strPlant"` and `itemValue="strPlant"` make sense only if you are passing an  instance of HashMap to `items=""` attribute.

[Spring Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html)